# How to add XamlHost to WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml-islands

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64661834/how-to-use-the-correct-windowsruntime-dll-in-wpf-for-xaml-islands) issue, I migrated my WPF project (which was targeting .NET Framework) to target .NET Core 3.1. Theoretically this step would allow to use `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost` in order to host Windows 10 controls in my WPF app.

I created a new WPF project, which targets .NET Core, and moved the source code to this new project and solved every dependency issue.

As I installed the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost` library (6.1.2) via Nuget Package Manager (just the following line was added to the `.csproj` file: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost" Version="6.1.2" />`), the project could compile but couldn't run. It displayed the following error message:

[image: configuration error message]

When I removed the library dependency, the project started again...

I think the problem is not with the manifest file, because it has not changed. Then what could be the problem? Where to start to search it? Maybe with one of the other dependencies? Where can I find that application event log? (I was searching a lot, but not found).

I tried the [sample app](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Islands-Samples/tree/master/Samples/WPF) and it works fine, so maybe is it possible that something interferes with the `XamlHost` in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could add the `XamlHost`. The conflict was with the Dpi awareness settings in the manifest file. Removed the following lines:

```
<dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
<dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563725/microsoft-store-certification-fails-due-to-dpi-awareness/60596815#60596815) issue, the dpi awareness should be set to `PerMonitorV2` in order to be able to submit the application to the store. Now I had to remove because it was in conflict with the `XamlHost`.

I'm wondering if I can release the app with this modification...